# Using "media" uploadType in Ruby Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: ruby, google-api-ruby-client

I'm in the process of writing up some sample code, and I'm having some trouble getting the "media" uploadType option to work correctly.

I'm learning both Ruby and the APIs at the same time, so bear with me - but this (and several slight variations) is what I was trying:

```
media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('file.txt', 'text/plain')
media_insert_result = client.execute(
  api_method: storage.objects.insert,
  parameters: {
    uploadType: 'media', 
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
    name: OBJECT_NAME
  },
  media: media
)
```

Everything works happily for resumable, multipart, and metadata uploads, but I can't seem to get media to work. Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.